# Lookup value based on part of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have a list of tasks (column A) , with one master ID number (Column B)
This master project number is a combination of text and numbers in format ABC.001

I have another list of sub tasks, each of which begins with a master project number. (Column C)

In column D, I want the name of the task based on lookup of the first 7 characters in the sub project number. See example attached.

How do I get values in column D? I just cannot get it to work.

```
Name of Task (A)  Task Master(B)Task Sub Number(C)  Result I Need Here (D)
APPLE             ABC.001       ABC.001.01          Apple
ORANGE            ABC.002       ABC.002.01          Orange
BANANA            ABC.003       ABC.001.002         Apple
                                ABC.001.01.01.003   Apple
                                ABC.001.01.01.004   Apple
                                ABC.003.01.05       Banana
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name range A2:B4 as TaskTable and you name range B2:B4 as TaskMaster you can use this formula to obtain the result you need in Column D

Cell D2

```
=INDEX(TaskTable,MATCH(LEFT(C2,7),TaskMaster,0),1)
```

Cell D3

```
=INDEX(TaskTable,MATCH(LEFT(C3,7),TaskMaster,0),1)
```

And so on..

Double click the small black box in the right bottom corner of D1 to fill the formula down to your last row of data.

Hope this helps.